# Iterating Range of Numbers in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, range

A website gives information based on a certain Zipcode. I'm using Selenium to try and capture info about every Zipcode. I imagine I use a for loop and range to get all information?

Part (1) I enter this code in the search box which gives info based on the #### zipcode

```
.send_keys('####').send_keys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I find the result based on the #### and then print out the info:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.result-name') print(element)
```

How do I collect info for the range (1000,10000) of Zipcodes? This range will enter part (1)

Thanks!

Comment: You want to iterate over a range?  `for x in range(1000,10000)` and then call `send_keys(x)`.

Comment: What info are you trying to print?  The way you have it now will just print out the webdriver info about the element found and not what is being displayed.

Comment: I would suggest either API or head-less for this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Please be clear about what you want to ask. Add some snippet of code and challenges that you are facing. Please feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a Range object:

```
for x in range(1,4):
    print(x)

    #=> 1
    #=> 2
    #=> 3
```

But zipcodes are alphabetical, so you would need to convert them to strings via `str()`:

```
for x in range(1,4):
    print(x)
    print(type(x))
    print(type(str(x)))     
    #=> 1
    #=> <class 'int'>
    #=> <class 'str'>
    ...
```

After generating a collection of string-ified zipcodes, you launch can launch a browser and start an iteration of requests/actions.